# How do you get statistics on Threads data of previously run process?

Tags: linux, multithreading, stat

How can we get information on thread spun by previously executed processes ?

I had a heavy CPU utilizing process completed running, now I need to get its Thread information. Can we get thread information / statistics after process has completed executing ?

Comment: What programming language do you use? shell? C++? What information do you want to obtain?

Comment: I use shell.  I want to know how much threads were spun to complete a data, how much threads were created to write data / read data to disk, how much CPU they utilized, why was there a high IOWAIT, . These info could be got by getting know threads statistics when a my process was executing.

Comment: Do you know the ID of the thread?

Comment: I want to know how would I find that ?

Comment: Issue is process has already completed. How would I find the thread ID?